# Putting the endpoints of a line segment "over" the line segment

Tags: tikz-pgf

The display that `TikZ` gives for the following code is a line segment with endpoints.  The line segment is drawn over the endpoints.

How do I put the endpoints over the line segment?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yellow, line width=0.1pt] (-1.75,-1.75) grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5]  (2.75,1.75);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,1.75) +(0,0.25cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-1.75) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-1.75,0) +(-0.25cm,0) -- (2.75,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\filldraw (-1,-1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
\filldraw (2,1) circle[radius=1.5pt];

\node[left, outer sep=2pt, fill=white] at (-1,-1) {P};
\node[right, outer sep=2pt, fill=white] at (2,1) {Q};
\coordinate (P) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (Q) at (2,1);

\draw[green!20!white] (P) -- (Q);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `\coordinate`s, use the `\node`s themselves with `label` like

```
%\filldraw (-1,-1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
%\filldraw (2,1) circle[radius=1.5pt];

\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]left:$P$}] (P) at (-1,-1) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt, label={[fill=white]right:$Q$}] (Q) at (2,1) {};
%\coordinate (P) at (-1,-1);
%\coordinate (Q) at (2,1);

\draw[green!20!white] (P) -- (Q);
```

Your code simplifies a lot.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yellow, line width=0.1pt] (-1.75,-1.75) grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5]  (2.75,1.75);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,1.75) +(0,0.25cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-1.75) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-1.75,0) +(-0.25cm,0) -- (2.75,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};
%\filldraw (-1,-1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
%\filldraw (2,1) circle[radius=1.5pt];

\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]left:$P$}] (P) at (-1,-1) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt, label={[fill=white]right:$Q$}] (Q) at (2,1) {};
%\coordinate (P) at (-1,-1);
%\coordinate (Q) at (2,1);

\draw[green!20!white] (P) -- (Q);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like two edits.  The letters "P" and "Q" should be in script.  Why doesn't `label=left:$P$` put "P" in script?  I also want to put the letters in a circular node (filled with white) so that the "P" and "Q" are over the grid ... but I don't want this white, circular node to interfere with the endpoints.

Comment: @user74973 What do you mean by `script`?

Comment: Italics. _______

Comment: @user74973 OK, please see the edit.  You have to use `label={[fill=white]right:$Q$}`.

Comment: Thanks!  I will look at the manual later for `label={[fill=white]right:$Q$}`.

Comment: @user74973 `label` is a node too. Hence you can pass other options alongside `fill=white` for example say `[fill=white,text=red]`.